# Plotly: combine timeseries/candlestick chart with bubble/scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, bubble-chart

Is it possible to to combine candlestick charts with bubble scatter plot with plotly? Sample data:

```
| date       | open  | high  | low   | close | value |
| --------   | ------| ------| ------| ------| ------|
| 01/09/2021 | 64.00 | 65.25 | 64.80 | 65.00 | 1000  |
| 02/09/2021 | 65.00 | 66.25 | 65.00 | 66.00 | NaN   |
| 03/09/2021 | 66.00 | 67.00 | 65.95 | 67.00 | NaN   |
| 04/09/2021 | 68.00 | 68.25 | 66.85 | 68.00 | -500  |
| 07/09/2021 | 68.00 | 68.50 | 66.75 | 67.00 | NaN   |
| 08/09/2021 | 67.00 | 67.25 | 64.50 | 65.00 | NaN   |
| 09/09/2021 | 65.00 | 65.50 | 64.00 | 64.00 | 2000  |
```

For example I want a bubble to appear on the price levels of 65,68,64, whereas the bubbles with positive values to be green (as on 01/09/2021 and 09/09/2021) and those with negative values to be red(as on 04/09/2021).

For now I have the following code, which gives me a chart as in the image attached.

[image]

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Candlestick(x=df['date'],
                open=df['open'],
                high=df['high'],
                low=df['low'],
                close=df['close'],
                yaxis= "y2"  
            ), 
        row = 1, col=2
    )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(line=dict(color='rgb(30,46,185)'),
    x=df['date'], y = df['close'],
    mode='markers',
             ),
        row = 1, col=2
    )
```

Comment: your sample data is incomplete,  it does not have all 5 columns for OHLC

Comment: Your are right. I thought OHL is not important for solving the problem. However, I've just added imaginary OHL to the sample data.- @Rob Raymond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- sample data set in question is incomplete, so used **plotly** sample data set. Renamed columns to make them consistent with your code
- you can create a scatter trace and candlestick trace in same figure. One key requirement, make sure the are both using same `yaxis`. By default candlestick uses `y2`
- colors or bubbles / scatter is defined by an array, where no value to plot (`NaN`) it uses transparent.
- it appears you have used sub-plots so attention will need to be applied to making **yaxis** consistent

```
# fmt: off
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df = df.rename(columns={s: t for s, t in zip(df.columns, [c.strip("APPL").strip(".").lower() for c in df.columns])})
df = df.head(20)
df["value"] = np.random.choice([1000, -500, np.nan], len(df))
# fmt: on

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=df["date"],
            y=df["close"],
            mode="markers",
            marker_color=np.select(
                [df["value"] > 0, df["value"] < 0], ["green", "red"], "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            ),
            yaxis="y2",
            name="Bubble"
        ),
        go.Candlestick(
            x=df["date"],
            open=df["open"],
            high=df["high"],
            low=df["low"],
            close=df["close"],
            yaxis="y2",
            name="Candlestick"
        ),
    ]
).update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
```

[image]

#### continuous color for "bubble"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# fmt: off
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df = df.rename(columns={s: t for s, t in zip(df.columns, [c.strip("APPL").strip(".").lower() for c in df.columns])})
df = df.head(20)
df["value"] = np.random.randint(-500, 1000, len(df))
df.loc[df.sample(10).index, "value"] = np.nan
# fmt: on

go.Figure(
    [
        px.scatter(
            df.loc[
                ~df["value"].isna(),
            ],
            x="date",
            y="close",
            color="value",
            color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
        )
        .update_traces(yaxis="y2", marker_size=20)
        .data[0],
        go.Candlestick(
            x=df["date"],
            open=df["open"],
            high=df["high"],
            low=df["low"],
            close=df["close"],
            yaxis="y2",
            name="Candlestick",
        ),
    ]
).update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, coloraxis_colorbar_y=0.35)
```

[image]

Comment: Further to my question: I try to make the colors for every 'bubble' different depending on the value. Assuming all values in df['value'] are positive, I want the higher values to be with darker color and vice versa. I tried this line: marker=dict(size=20,color=df['value'], colorscale='Viridis'), but this doesn't change anything. - @Rob Raymond

Comment: it's so much simpler to do continuous colors with Plotly Express